# Get hold of warnings from cython pyximport compile (distutils build output?)

Tags: python, cython, distutils

When I compile a cython .pyx file from IdleX the build shell window pops up with a bunch of warnings to close again after less than a second.

I think pyximport uses distutils to build. How can I write the gcc warnings to a file or have the output delay or wait for keypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done anything with cython myself but I guess you could use a commandline for the building. That way you would see all the messages until you close the actual commandline unless some really fatal error happens.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a .pyxbld file to specify Cython build settings.

Say you are trying to compile **yourmodule.pyx**, simply create a file in the same directory named **yourmodule.pyxbld** containing:

```
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    ext = Extension(name = modname,
        sources=[pyxfilename])

    return ext

def make_setup_args():
    return dict(script_args=['--verbose'])
```

The --verbose flag makes pyximport print gcc's output.

Note that you can easily add extra compiler and linker flags. For example, to use Cython's prange() function you must compile and link against the OpenMP library, this is specified using keywords to the Extension class:

```
ext = Extension(name = modname,
    sources=[pyxfilename],
    extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'],
    extra_link_args=['-fopenmp'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is how you could do to get the output in a file (in case the warnings overflow the command prompt) :

This is for Windows, but you can easily adapt for *unices :

```
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;../../../DEPENDENCIES/Cython-0.18
SET PATH=%PATH%;../../../DEPENDENCIES/Cython-0.18/bin

python setup.py build_ext --inplace > output.log
```